# How to upload metadata of Token-2022 Program?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, token

I want to mint an SPL fungible token, but when I tried to mint it, I encountered issues with my metadata. Should I upload separate metadata for this?

https://solscan.io/token/5vHo6Sh55T1iQsPGfNngHghpotuWVEkdzCmcCFbkQrbg?cluster=devnet#analysis

I followed the Quicknode Guide to mint the token.

https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/token-2022/transfer-fees?_gl=1*sni6uq*_ga*MTQ4MzI1ODI5MS4xNjcyNjQyMTY1*_ga_DYE4XLEMH3*MTcwNjI1NDg2OS4xMDIuMS4xNzA2MjU1NjYxLjYwLjAuMA..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a metadata file and host your Token ICON.if you have created the token with token-22 then you need to follow the below code.

> token_metadata.js

```
import { createV1, updateV1, Collection, Creator, Uses, CreateV1InstructionAccounts, CreateV1InstructionData, TokenStandard, CollectionDetails, PrintSupply, UpdateV1InstructionAccounts, Data } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import { PublicKey, createSignerFromKeypair, none, percentAmount, publicKey, signerIdentity, some } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { fromWeb3JsKeypair, fromWeb3JsPublicKey } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters';
import * as bs58 from "bs58";

const SPL_TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID: PublicKey = publicKey(
    'TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb'
);


export function loadWalletKey(keypairFile: string): web3.Keypair {
    const fs = require("fs");
    const loaded = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
        new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypairFile).toString())),
    );
    return loaded;
}

const INITIALIZE = false;
async function main() {
    console.log("Metadata Updation Started ️ ");
    const myKeypair = loadWalletKey("authorityWallet.json");
    const mint = new web3.PublicKey("Token-Mint_address");

    const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
    const signer = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, fromWeb3JsKeypair(myKeypair))
    umi.use(signerIdentity(signer, true))

    const ourMetadata = { // TODO change those values!
        name: "Asvoria",
        symbol: "ASV",
        description: "Asvoria’s utility token is $ASV, which will be used as the default currency in Asvoria’s entire ecosystem consisting of the metaverse, NFT marketplace, and other upcoming ventures.",
        uri: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/0xlazytron/a625b73ac8589cbe55da9c66a05c28b7/raw/521d2c0ee1045073495df784c0e552faecf9ad6b/metadata.json",
    }
    if (INITIALIZE) {
        const onChainData = {
            ...ourMetadata,
            // we don't need that
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0, 2),
            creators: none<Creator[]>(),
            collection: none<Collection>(),
            uses: none<Uses>(),
        }
        const accounts: CreateV1InstructionAccounts = {
            mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
            splTokenProgram: SPL_TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        }
        const data: CreateV1InstructionData = {
            ...onChainData,
            isMutable: true,
            discriminator: 0,
            tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
            collectionDetails: none<CollectionDetails>(),
            ruleSet: none<PublicKey>(),
            createV1Discriminator: 0,
            primarySaleHappened: true,
            decimals: none<number>(),
            printSupply: none<PrintSupply>(),
        }
        const txid = await createV1(umi, { ...accounts, ...data }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
        console.log(bs58.encode(txid.signature))
    } else {
        const onChainData = {
            ...ourMetadata,
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
            creators: none<Creator[]>(),
            collection: none<Collection>(),
            uses: none<Uses>(),
        }
        const accounts: UpdateV1InstructionAccounts = {
            mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
        }
        const data = {
            discriminator: 0,
            data: some<Data>(onChainData),
            updateV1Discriminator: 0,
        }
        const txid = await updateV1(umi, { ...accounts, ...data }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
        console.log(bs58.encode(txid.signature))
    }


}

main();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the token metadata extension that's available directly inside of the token-2022 mint. When initializing your mint, you'll need to run:

```
$ spl-token create-token --enable-metadata --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb
```

And then to initialize the metadata, you can run:

```
$ spl-token initialize-metadata <MINT_ADDRESS> <NAME> <SYMBOL> <URI>
```

And from there, you can update your metadata:

```
$ spl-token update-metadata <MINT_ADDRESS> <KEY> <VALUE>
```

Answer (score 0):

using createV1 function you can upload metadata for token 2022:

```
const { signature } = await createV1(umi, {
      mint: publicKey(mint.publicKey),
      authority: umi.identity,
      name: 'My Token',
      symbol: '$MTO',
      splTokenProgram: publicKey(TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58()),
      uri: '...',
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
      tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
```

Comment: Thanks,, but I want to upload from the frontend. I'm facing issue uploading from frontend

Comment: this is code for front end, you can go to metaplex and check how to create Umi for wallet adapter for your react / netxt js app